# Controller is only saving 1 variable into database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a HttpPost Controller which I am trying to use to take data from a View and store model data into my local mvc database. Although when I test out the form (which has 4 inputs for the user to enter), submit it and then check the database, only School.Date is saved into the table and the other 3 variables are blank (even though I entered them in along with School.Date).

My School Model:

```
namespace BookingSys.Models
{
  public class School
  {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
  }
}
```

My controllers for the Booking View:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Booking()
    {
         var model = db.Dates.ToList();
         return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Booking(School model)
    {
        db.Schools.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Booking");
    }
```

My Booking View:

```
@model List<BookingSys.Models.Datepicker>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Booking";
}

<h2>School Bookings</h2>

<form asp-controller="School" asp-action="Booking" method="post">
  <br />
  <div>
    <label for="Date">Choose Date:</label>
    <input asp-for="School.Date" id="txtDate" name="Date" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <label for="Name">School Name:</label>
    <input asp-for="School.Name" id="txtName" name="Name: " />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
    <input asp-for="School.Email" id="txtEmail" name="Email: " />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <label for="Phone">Phone Number:</label>
    <input asp-for="School.PhoneNumber" id="txtPhone" name="Phone Number: 
" />
</div>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>

<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

// jQuery UI Datepicker
@section scripts {

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
            jQuery(function () {

                var enableDays = ['@Html.Raw(string.Join("','", 
Model.Select(d => d.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))))'];

                console.log(enableDays);

                function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
                    var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date)
                    console.log(sdate)
                    if ($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
                        return [true];
                    }
                    return [false];
                }

                $("#txtDate").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy",
                    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,



                });

            });
</script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<style>
 .my-class a {
    background-color: #07ea69 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
</style>
```

This is what the db context looks like; date saves no problem but name, email and phoneNumber are not saving for some reason. Anybody know why?

[image: db]

Cheers

Comment: Do not use a number to store phone numbers. It would not account for certain cases, like if there's a leading zero, or exceptionally long numbers.

Comment: @cost thanks mate, what should I use instead?

Comment: Store it as a string, varchar should be fine unless you expect to store unicode characters with it for some reason, then go with nvarchar. You'll need to make sure to handle storing/loading numbers consistently, since there are lots of common formats people use. Like () or - or just numbers. You'll probably have an easier time if you store them all in a consistent format. That's less important if you're only displaying it on a screen, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `name` attributes are incorrect for your text boxes except for the Date field. The `name` is what gets bound to the model when you POST.

`name="Name: "` should be `name="Name"`, it should match the field name on the model. (it seems like you meant to use the `placeholder` attribute - i.e. `placeholder="Name: "`)

I actually don't think you need to add them manully, because when you make a `asp-for` input it should add the `id` and `name` for you.

So simply remove all `id` and `name` attributes from your `asp-for` inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Works fine except for the PhoneNumber. I'm guessing the form is passing a string for phoneNumber into the controller? and this is why it is not being saved into the int column in the database? Do you know how I can fix this if that is the case? Cheers

Comment: It looks like it will only save a small int into the database. Any large number i.e. a phone number will not save

Comment: ya that sounds like a different issue. fyi you can add `type="number"` to your PhoneNumber input to limit the input to integers